# MySQL how to combine not null fields that share the same ID into 1 row per ID

Tags: mysql

What is the most sufficient way to combine rows with null sharing the same id:

```
Having this table:

| UserID | FNAME | LNAME |
|--------|-------|-------|
| 1      | NULL  | NULL  |
| 1      | jhon  | NULL  |
| 1      | NULL  | doe   |
| 2      | NULL  | NULL  |
| 2      | Jarry | NULL  |
| 2      | NULL  | Lauf  |

want to get:
| UserID | FNAME | LNAME |
|--------|-------|-------|
| 1      | jhon  | doe   |
| 2      | Jarry | Lauf  |
```

Comment: What if there are rows `(1,'john', NULL)` and `(1,'jim', NULL)`? What value should be used? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate by user and then take the max of the two name columns:

```sql
SELECT UserID, MAX(FNAME) AS FNAME, MAX(LNAME) AS LNAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY UserID;
```